# I get the "FilenotfoundExceptionunhandled" ? in Console application while displaying the SharePoint site list name

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, console-application

Error Details:

1. The Web application at
   http://dev001aaamaaind:333/ could
   not be found. Verify that you have
   typed the URL correctly. If the URL
   should be serving existing content,
   the system administrator may need to
   add a new request URL mapping to the
   intended application.

   string urlSite = "http://dev001aaamaaind:333/";

   > ```
   >         using (SPSite sc = new SPSite(urlSite))//Getting Error in the line
   >         {
   >             SPWeb site = sc.RootWeb;
   >             foreach (SPList list in site.Lists)
   >             {
   >                 if (!list.Hidden)
   >                     Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
   >             }
   >         }
   > ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://spserver2010.blogspot.com/2010/09/visual-studio-2010-beta-console.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set the Platform in the Project Properties Build tab to either to x64 or Any CPU. This is one common issue that hit when developing using SharePoint 2010 as it is based on 64 bit Arch.

Comment: thanks man i solved it already..U are the only guy reply for sharepoint question from india!!!

Comment: @Ayyappan: Glad that you got it solved, it would be helpful for others to know how it solved it, share your answer. Lots of people out there in SO for SharePoint :)

Comment: Mark it as Answer so that it will help someone.